# Loop through NSArray and copy to new swift Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

Hey guys im very new to swift and im trying to loop through an NSArray imported from a plist which I then want to populate a 2D swift array with a list of CGPoints.

My plist is set out for with each letter of the Alphabet, within each letter I have an array[][] first row is strokes and second row then holds x,y coordinates.

[image]

My variables:

```
var letterPoints: NSDictionary?
var letterPointsArray: NSArray?
var letterCGPoints = [[Any]]()
```

My code:

```
    letterPoints = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "LetterPoints", ofType: "plist")!)
    letterPointsArray = (letterPoints?.value(forKey: image)) as? NSArray

    var i = 0
    for strokes in letterPointsArray! as! [[Int]]
    {
        for points in strokes
        {
            let x = strokes[i][0] // Error Value of type 'Int' has no subscripts.
            let y = strokes[i][1]

            letterCGPoints[i].append(CGPoint(x: x,y: y))
        }
        i = i+1
    }
```

Im getting an error when assigning x and y - Value of type 'Int' has no subscripts.

I originally had this working when I had it set up without the extra row for each stroke but after turning it into a 2D array I'm now struggling to work with it and am quite lost finding the correct way of going about it from my online searches and looking through stackoverflow. Please excuse my ignorance and complete lack of knowledge in swift, would really appreciate some advice on the best way solve this. Thanks :)

Comment: Add your code as text.not screenshots

Comment: Sorry about that have edited the post.

Comment: So `strokes` is a 2D array, `points` is a 1D array. So why are you trying to access it like a 2D array? Should there be one lesser `for` loop?

Comment: Because I also need to loop through each set of points within the strokes and append them one by one to the CGPoint array. So each stroke will have multiple x,y values. I still think I need the extra loop but it should probably more like points[0] and points[1] but that is also giving me same error

Comment: Don't use `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSDictionary(contentsOf`, `value(forKey` in Swift. And avoid `Any` as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your array correctly from the start

```
var letterPointsArray: [[[Int]]]?
```

and then cast it directly

```
letterPointsArray = (letterPoints?.value(forKey: "image")) as? [[[Int]]]
```

or even better in one line

```
 let letterPointsArray = (letterPoints?.value(forKey: "image")) as? [[[Int]]]
```

And by using `enumerated()` you can then iterate over the array

```
if let letterPointsArray = (letterPoints?.value(forKey: "image")) as? [[[Int]]] {
    for (i, strokes) in letterPointsArray.enumerated() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your strokes array. The following code might work.

```
let points: [[Int]] = [[10, 20], [30, 40]]
        var i = 0
        var j = 1
        for point in points {
            let a = point[i]
            let b = point[j]
            print(a,b)
        }
        i+=1
        j+=1
```